# Default \mathbb with some XITS Math symbols too

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

This example doesn't give me the good bbold R symbol when the line `\setmathfont[range=\sslash]{XITS Math}` is active.
So the example below is the behaviour I would like to have.

How can I get the **same**/default R symbol **with** the line `\setmathfont[range=\sslash]{XITS Math}` ?

Thank you very much.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[tuenc]{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{CMU Serif} %needed for me to get small-bold caps
    \setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
    \setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

%\setmathfont[range=\sslash]{XITS Math}

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{R}$


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ranges is unfortunately buggy. Redeclaring the range for `\mathbb` seems to solve the issue, but maybe raises other problems. Test it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{CMU Serif} %needed for me to get small-bold caps
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
\setmathfont[range=\sslash]{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range=bb]{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{R}$

$\sslash$

\end{document}
```

[image]